# Is controller a valid keyword that can be used in a fx:reference or expression binding in an FXML?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, fxml, fxmlloader

I defined an FXML file that contains an fx:reference element using a source attribute containing the keyword `controller`. Like this `<fx:reference source="controller.viewModel"/>`. So the fx:reference references the controller of the FXML file.
And the good thing, this syntax works.

I found a few examples that are using the keyword `controller` in expression bindings, like this `<Label text="${controller.text}"/>`

But I found no documentation about this keyword `controller`.

I checked the documentation at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html.
And the keyword `controller` is not mentioned.
I only found an indication about it in the https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#CONTROLLER_KEYWORD

My question: is this keyword `controller` a feature of FXML?
Or is my syntax just a hack that works? And will this hack still work in new version of the FXMLLoader?

This is my code:

ParentPane.fxml

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import eu.primion.fxmlproject.fxmlview.ChildPane?>
<fx:root type="VBox" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
     <ChildPane fx:id="childPane">
       <viewModel>
         <fx:reference source="controller.viewModel"/>
       </viewModel>
     </ChildPane>
   </children>
</fx:root>
```

ParentPane.java

```
public class ParentPane extends VBox
{
    @FXML
    private ChildPane childPane;

    private final ViewModel viewModel;

    public ParentPane(final ViewModel viewModel)
    {
        this.viewModel = viewModel;

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ParentPane.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);
        try
        {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }

    public ViewModel getViewModel()
    {
        return this.viewModel;
    }
}
```

ChildPane.fxml

```
<fx:root type="VBox" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
         <TextField fx:id="textField" />
   </children>
</fx:root>
```

ChildPane.java

```
public class ChildPane extends VBox
{
    @FXML
    private TextField textField;

    private final ViewModel viewModel;

    public ChildPane(@NamedArg("viewModel") final ViewModel viewModel)
    {
        this.viewModel = viewModel;
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ChildPane.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);
        try
        {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }

    public void initialize()
    {
      this.textField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(this.viewModel.textProperty());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not explicitly documented, but the controller is added to the FXML loader's [namespace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#getNamespace--), and so it is accessible via expressions in the FXML via the expression variable `controller`. The same is true for the expression variables `resources` (which gives access to the resource bundle set on the FXML loader, or passed to the `load()` method) and `location` (which gives access to the URL representing the location of the FXML).

While this isn't explicitly documented, the FXML documentation does contain an [example using this technique](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#expression_handlers); so it would be extremely surprising if this were changed in a future release. In general, the behavior of a `FXMLLoader` is not well documented.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Is <fx:reference source="controller.viewModel"/> the only way to pass the Viewmodel object from the ParentPane.fxml to the ChildPane.fxml?

Comment: @JohanDeSchutter You could also pass it from the Java code, in the `initialize()` method. You would need to define a setter method in `ChildPane` for it, and it wouldn't be initialized until that setter was called. I think, on balance, the way you are doing it is preferable.

Comment: @JohanDeSchutter I *think* you can also do, e.g. `fxmlLoader.getNamespace().put("viewModel", viewModel)` in the `ParentPane` constructor, before calling `fxmlLoader.load()`, and then in the FXML just refer to `$viewModel` or `<fx:reference source="viewModel"/>`.

Comment: Exactly, I used a setter method in the ChildPane, but it moves the binding of the properties from the initialize to the setter method.